Incorrect FCM registration token on iOS devices
My website is utilizing FCM push notifications to inform the user about time-critical news.
Subscribing to and receiving these push notifications do work, on Android and on iOS devices. But for some reason on iOS devices, after 2-3 days of being subscribed to the push notifications, the device does not receive the notifications anymore.
The server-logs (server is used to trigger and send the push notifications using FCM) do not show any error when calling send/sendEachForMulticast. The promises resolve successfully, which should indicate that the registration token is not in stale/invalid state because in this case the promise would be rejected.
Can anyone help me with this? Or did anyone experience the same problem?
